# Error on Wordpress Login

Tags: login, security

I am editing my wordpress site before and nothing is wrong until I change my ISP then this error came out when I try to login on my site:

> Not Acceptable!
>
> An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be
>   found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

What would be the best solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had some problem with `Mod_Security`, login , Rest API (mobile app access), ...

You can change roles of `Mod_Security`

Comment: Where is that? Sorry I am a newbie in terms of this problem.

Comment: it Depends on Your Issue, read document of `Mod_Security`

Comment: is that can be found on the cpanel?

Comment: i tried it on WHMk

Comment: Whatever *that* is.